Is there a way to represent time deltas in Python that differentiates between "1 day" and "24 hours"?
I'm currently working on a reminder bot project that supports recurring reminders. For example, a user can specify that they want their reminder to repeat in intervals of "3 days", "12 hours", "2 weeks", so on. In particular, there are two cases that should be handled:

Intervals of "1 day", where a reminder for 3pm will repeat every day at 3pm, even across daylight savings
Intervals of "24 hours", where a reminder for 3pm will repeat exactly 24 hours later. In a timezone where daylight savings happens, this may end up occurring at 2pm or 4pm.

In most cases these two are equivalent, but as noted in timezones with daylight savings there's an important distinction.
Here is some example code of what I want to happen, using the built-in timedelta object:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

# 2024-10-05 18:00:00+10:00
# Note: Australia/Sydney begins DST on Oct 6, offset going from +10 to +11
dt = datetime(2024, 10, 5, 18, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Australia/Sydney"))

# Expected: 2024-10-06 18:00:00+11:00 (still 6pm, but with the new DST offset)
print(dt + timedelta(days=1))

# Expected: 2024-10-06 19:00:00+11:00 (exactly 24 hours later)
print(dt + timedelta(hours=24))

However, this does not seem to work as it normalises hours=24 to days=1 and so the two lines are equivalent. So far, I have not been able to find a Python object that can represent these intervals separately. relativedelta from dateutil as well as the Timedelta from pandas both have this normalising behaviour.
Is there a workaround or library that I can use for this?

Unfortunately, with pytz and Python datetime, you have to work with the limitations which is to say you have to work with UTC for conversion, only convert to local time for display. Yes I will agree that this is not ideal because there are good reasons to store the timestamp with the relevant timezone in order to better track future changes, but Python standard library makes this not possible.

a reminder for 3pm ... may end up occurring at 2pm or 4pm I can't imagine an actual use case for this behavior.  Did an actual user ask for this?

Working with time offsets is problematic in general. A second is the longest time unit that has a defined length. But working with just them might also lead to unexpected results if a day is not exactly 86400s long. So Python used a combination of seconds and days that has its own set of quirks.

More about timedelta having only days and seconds - see thread. It doesn't actually know about hours, the constructor simply makes assumptions that every hour has 3600 seconds (which may not be true given existence of positive and potentially negative leap seconds).

@JohnGordon there could be situations where it's important to do an action exactly (or as close as possible to) every 24 hours e.g. taking measurements for an experiment. A measurement (or other action) being 25/23 hours after after the previous would be unacceptable in such a situation.

I think timedelta won't work in your case. It rather looks like a schedule where you can iterate through a sequence of local datetimes, their UTC timestamps might have different timedeltas. I'd rater use schedule as the primary object.
